# Default Thumbnail Not Showing

Tags: javascript

I found a script to use with Blogger and I altered it to suit my needs. It's supposed to show thumbnail of the posts by grabbing the first image in the post. The script works and will show the thumbnail of posts with no errors. However, the script doesn't show the default thumbnail if there is no image within the post. Instead, it throws an error in the Chrome console: `> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILL`

This is what I have:

```
            <!-- large thumbnail on homepage -->
            <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>
              <b:if cond='data:post.isFirstPost'>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    //<![CDATA[
                    function bp_thumbnail_resize(image_url)
                    {
                        var image_size=320;
                        var show_default_thumbnail=true;
                        var default_thumbnail="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-BD9oqMTSB5s/UzhXikZyTmI/AAAAAAAAawY/pa9RvkRXzyY/s320/default-post-image.png";
                        if(show_default_thumbnail == true && image_url == "") image_url= default_thumbnail;
                        image_tag='<div style="background: url('+image_url.replace('/s72-c/','/s'+image_size+'-c/')+'); background-size: cover;" class="post-thumb"></div>';
                        if(image_url!="") return image_tag; else return "";
                    }
                    //]]>
                    </script>
              </b:if>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    document.write(bp_thumbnail_resize("<data:post.thumbnailUrl/>"));
                </script>
            </b:if>
```

The Chrome console says the problem is: `<data:post.thumbnailUrl/>`, but as I said it works fine if there is an image within the post. The problem only occurs when trying to show the default image.

How can this be fixed? I don't even see the problem. Perhaps there is a better way to show a default image if there is no image within the post?

Comment: how do you call the function, once you get the image tag do you add it to the DOM, any example pages or JS error? You need to add more information.

Comment: Why do you have it wrapped in a CDATA tag? And would it not be simple to use the onerror method in your image tag?

Comment: @infinity updated question with error info.

Comment: @E.Maggini it's a blogger template. It's required to pass validation upon submission.

Comment: I updated the code I was using, and added more surrounding bits & problem area.

Comment: I confirmed the code of this function is valid with no error, so probably the problem is the outside.

Comment: @KenOKABE If I remove the script I posted here, then the Uncaught Syntax error disappears.

Comment: Interesting. http://jsfiddle.net/LeBe5/ some test for you.

Comment: I narrowed down the problem I think. It's the `<data:post.thumbnailUrl/>`, but I tried replacing the '<' & '>' with '&#60;' and '&#62;' and all it ended up doing was showing the `<data:post.thumbnailUrl/>` in the source instead of '<div style="" etc.

Comment: try to do a console.log(image_url) on the start of the bp_thumbnail_resize function. I'm pretty sure it's not an empty string when there is no image.

Answer (score 1):

Bacause you added `if(image_url!="") return image_tag; else return "";` at the very end of function.

BTW, isnt it better to use `<b:if cond>` and `<b:else/>` pseudotags?
Below I attach quite better solution:

```
        <!-- large thumbnail on homepage -->
        <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>
          <b:if cond='data:post.isFirstPost'>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                //<![CDATA[
                function bp_thumbnail_resize(image_url)
                {
                    var image_size=320;
                    image_tag='<div style="background: url('+image_url.replace('/s72-c/','/s'+image_size+'-c/')+'); background-size: cover;" class="post-thumb"></div>';
                }
                //]]>
                </script>
          </b:if>
            <b:if cond='data:post.thumbnailUrl'>
    <script type="text/javascript">
                document.write(bp_thumbnail_resize("<data:post.thumbnailUrl/>"));
            </script>
    <b:else/>
        <div style="background: url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-BD9oqMTSB5s/UzhXikZyTmI/AAAAAAAAawY/pa9RvkRXzyY/s320/default-post-image.png); background-size: cover;" class="post-thumb"></div>
    </b:if>
        </b:if>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work at all. It throws a "undefined" error everywhere there is supposed to be a thumbnail.

Comment: I did use the code below, but your condition statements and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Delete this code

```
if(show_default_thumbnail == true && image_url == "") image_url= default_thumbnail;
image_tag='<div style="background: url('+image_url.replace('/s72-c/','/s'+image_size+'-c/')+'); background-size: cover;" class="post-thumb"></div>';
if(image_url!="") return image_tag; else return "";
```

And change with this

```
    if(show_default_thumbnail == true) {
        if (image_url == "") image_url = default_thumbnail;
        image_tag='<div style="background: url('+image_url.replace('/s72-c/','/s'+image_size+'-c/')+'); background-size: cover;" class="post-thumb"></div>';
    }
    return image_tag;
```

Comment: It still says throws the illegal token error in the console, and the default doesn't show.

Comment: I did use the condition statements in the previous answer, but your code and it worked.